# Magento Api Methods Problems

Tags: php, magento

I overwrite the following API "Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2". 
There, I've added a few new methods.

Now I have tried over the SOAPv2 interface an "old" method call (the "create" method as for example). There I got the following error message: "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [3] Invalid api path. in...".

Do I need to list all the methods etc. api.xml "Create", "Update" in the?

Here's my code.

**api.xml**

```
<connector_category translate="title" module="connector">
    <model>MyCompany_MyModel_Model_Catalog_Category_Api</model>
    <title>Category API</title>
    <methods>
        <removeAllCategories translate="title" module="connector">
            <title>Retrieve Category ID from its name</title>
            <acl>catalog/category</acl>
        </removeAllCategories>
    </methods>
</connector_category>
```

**wsdl.xml**

```
<message name="catalogCategoryRemoveAllCategoriesRequest">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="product" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="productIdentifierType" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="catalogCategoryRemoveAllCategoriesResponse">
        <part name="result" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </message>
    <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <operation name="catalogCategoryRemoveAllCategories">
            <documentation>Remove all product assignments from a category</documentation>
            <input message="typens:catalogCategoryRemoveAllCategoriesRequest"/>
            <output message="typens:catalogCategoryRemoveAllCategoriesResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="catalogCategoryRemoveAllCategories">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}"/>
        </port>
    </service>
```

**config.xml**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>MyCompany_MyModule_Resource</resourceModel>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
        <MyCompany_MyModule_resource>
            <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Resource</class>
        </MyCompany_MyModule_resource>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <category_api_v2>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Catalog_Category_Api_V2</category_api_v2>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
   </models>
</global>
```

**MyCompany/MyModule/Model/Catalog/Category/Api/V2.php**

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Catalog_Category_Api_V2 extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api_V2 {
    /**
     * @param $productId
     * @param null $identifierType
     * @return bool
     */
    public function removeAllCategories($productId, $identifierType = null)
    {
      $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

      $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

      foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
        $this->removeProduct($categoryId, $productId, $identifierType);
      }

      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you can share the code you have tried as well?

Comment: Sorry, i've forgotten it -.-